# JavaScript - Sort array by two integer properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array of objects:

```
const items = [
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "An Item", amount: 100, matches: 1 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 30, matches: 2 }
]
```

I need to sort these by `matches` and `amount`, so the final result looks like this:

```
[
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 30, matches: 2 },
    { name: "An Item", amount: 100, matches: 1 }
]
```

The first priority is to sort everything by `matches`, and then within those, I need to sort them by `amount`. I know I can sort by just `matches` or just `amount` like so:

```
items.sort((a, b) => a.matches - b.matches);
```

But how can I sort by both?

Comment: items.sort ( 1. Sort by matches. 2a. If equal, sort by amount. 2b. if not equal, do not do amount sort. ).  That is, equal  "matches"  does not resolve lesser or greater so go to the next sort. Repeat this pattern for all sort criteria. If they all resolve to equal, then the 2 items are equal and Javascript will not change their order. Once a sort resolves "not equal" then we know which is lesser.greater - no matter how subsequent criteria resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#sort`. Objects will get sorted based firstly on `matches` then on `amount`.

```js
const items = [
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 90, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 1 },
    { name: "An Item", amount: 80, matches: 1 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 30, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 40, matches: 1 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 50, matches: 1 },
    { name: "An Item", amount: 10, matches: 1 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 20, matches: 2 },
];

const r = [...items].sort((a, b) => b.matches - a.matches || b.amount - a.amount);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I'll accept the answer after the 10 minute period

Comment: Using `r` is slightly misleading. `items` is sorted in place.

Comment: @xehpuk You are absolutely right, added a spread just in case if immutability is a thing

Answer (score 0):

Another way to express sorting based on two critiera with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) would be:

```js
const items = [
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 100, matches: 2 },
    { name: "An Item", amount: 100, matches: 1 },
    { name: "Different Item", amount: 30, matches: 2 }
]

const result = items.sort((a, b) => {
  
  const matches = b.matches - a.matches;
  
  // If a.matches and b.matches are not the same,
  // sort this a and b pair based on matches in
  // descending order
  if(matches !== 0) {
    return matches;
  }
  
  // Here, the a and b pair have the same matches
  // value, so sort based on seondary criteria; 
  // amount in descending order
  return b.amount - a.amount;
});

console.log(result);
```